# Redux-like storage in GD

Tags: java, libgdx, storage

**Some background**

I've come from the world of web development. And it's a real trending in web to keep whole app's state in single global store (see [Redux](http://redux.js.org/), discussion about it's [benefits](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/3w8uey/what_are_the_real_benefits_of_using_fluxredux/)).

- Basically the main idea it makes the state management more
  predictable.

**Question**

I have no ideas how Redux-like architecture would fit for a game development.
My main fears it's about usage with main loop inside game and of course about performance.

*Did anyone use Redux-like store in GD, or it's a common anti-pattern*?

Thanks for opinions.

P.S. It's not really matter, but I use libGDX.

Comment: Generally you'll find StackExchange is better at answering "Here's a problem I have, what is a solution?" than it is at "Here's an interesting solution, does anyone use it to solve problems?" This is complicated in games by how secretive much of their development can be, with major game systems typically closed-source and guarded by NDAs outside of the bits we choose to share on devblogs & at trade conferences — so whether or not a number of released games used the solution you're wondering about, it would be hard to know.

Comment: @DMGregory Yeah, thanks. Perhaps I don't understand the nature of stackexchange's gamedev channel, cause I believe that this kind of questions it's more or less ok for SoF.
Also - yes it's really a hard question. But there are a number of indi developers and opensource engines. And I've found few games that was build with redux. But it was examples, not a real-world apps, so I assume that perhaps here someone can share his experience.
And I believe that redux can be implemented on top of any engine, such as unity. For me keep all state of your game logic in one place seems to be promising.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I'm currently making a game using React + Redux ([check it out here](http://react-rpg.com)). It would be better for a variety of reasons to using something like Unity in the long term, but for now, this is just my little experiment.

I was thinking the same thing as you and I come from web dev as well. And the Redux state management and debugger is pretty awesome once you start having a ton of things going on. Granted, my game works well with Redux because it's turn based. I've seen people do physics based games and whatnot, but the best games with Redux I've seen are either puzzles or mini RPGs.